# UITableView getting text of label from cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have UITableView question
1. I am making label in cells, cells in rows, rows in sections, sections in tableview now I am adding button in each cell so that I can get alert message box which show the text of label of that cell in which button exist 
I have tried my best to do this but cannot get text of exact label but problem is I am getting text of wrong label

```
- (IBAction)myShow:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",*****what to pass in here*****);
}
```

In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

I have this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
         mysampleimage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,3, 40, 40)];
         mysampleimage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
         mysampleimage.tag=13;
         [cell.contentView addSubview:mysampleimage];

         myButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         myButton.frame = CGRectMake(165, 10, 65, 30.);
         [myButton setTitle:@"Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         myButton.tag = 14;
         [cell addSubview:myButton];

         lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 6, 200, 43)];
         lbl.tag=12;
         [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
     }
     else
     {
         lbl=(UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:12];
         mysampleimage=(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:13];
         myButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:14];
     }

     myButton.accessibilityLabel = lbl.text;

     [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myShow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     return cell;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea with using buttons within tableviews is to attach the tag as the indexpath.row, and then fetch the data using sender.tag in the selector.

In your case, you may be able to get the text as follows:

```
- (IBAction)myShow:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton*) sender;
    UILabel *label = [button.superView viewWithTag:12];


    NSLog(@"%@",label.text);
    //Implement alert here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myShow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Since you reuse the cell, add add action outside the cell init, it will cause manay action add to a cell. This is why the alert show the wrong text. You need subclass a UITableViewCell, move the code above to the cell init method, and implement the action selector in your subClassCell.